# Monitor mode not sniffing from other devices on the same network

Tags: kali-linux, wireshark, raspberry-pi, 802.1x, icmp

i'm currently running a 802.11n adapter in monitor mode on a kali linux PC. Monitor mode was enabled using airmon-ng. On the same network as the kali linux PC are 2 raspberry pi devices.

Pinging from a Raspberry Pi device to the PC shows ICMP packets on wireshark, but pinging from a Raspberry Pi device to another Raspberry Pi device doesn't show anything on wireshark. Could there be any reason for this? Or a fix?

Comment: This isn't even a security question, try asking in: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ and It's kind of obvious, but both Raspberry Pi are connected through Wi-Fi right? The Kali Linux it's ON the PC, and not in a VM behind a NAT? (Because that wouldn't be the same network)

Answer (score 0):

If your other devices (Pi) are sending lan traffic over a network switch / router, it’s likely the traffic is not visible as the switch or router isn’t sending (routing) traffic to all ports (not spanning traffic to all ports). If your switch supports it you can look at making configuration changes to make it behave like a hub type device where all traffic goes out all ports, but that could easily end up in a packet storm or DoS condition.